# .Net Core Project Referencing .Net Frameork Projects Problems?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have a question about .net Core project.
I have a .Net Core Project referencing other projects. 
**The problem is that a few projects show the warning saying that "Package 'XXXXX' was restored using .NetFramework, Version=v4.6.1.... instead of targer framework .NetCoreApp".**
What kind of problems could I have?
Also can I deploy this in Linux for instance and still working fine?

[warning showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVPql.png)

Thanks guys

Comment: please edit your question and explain more specifically about your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread - [For a .Net Core 2.1 project, Why does Nuget restores .Net 4.6.1 packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189717/for-a-net-core-2-1-project-why-does-nuget-restores-net-4-6-1-packages)

What it basically means is the package you have loaded not suitable for .NET CORE, and was restored using a different version of .Net Framework.
Check if the package exists for .NET CORE (search thru NuGet Manager)

Regarding whether it will work on Linux or not - it depends on the package dependencies (e.g. if it is depending on WinForm for example, it probably won't work on Linux).
Even if it will work, I suggest finding a package suitable for .NET CORE.

Comment: He clearly states that he is referencing another project - not a package.

Comment: @cl0ud overlooked that. Still, I believe it means those projects have packages that aren’t compatible with .net core.